# Is there a way to use Spacer() in a ZStack? (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui

I have text on top of a rectangle through a ZStack and I was wondering if there was a way to limit the Spacer() amount within the rectangle.

```
           ZStack{
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width,
                           height: geometry.size.height/3.25)
                    .shadow(radius: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                
                //Words ontop of the Rectangle
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Hello World")
                    }.padding(.trailing, 40)
                
                Spacer() //<-- PROBLEM HERE
                }//.offset(y: -40)
            }
```

[image]

**What It Looks Like**

tl;dr:
I'd like to have is so that "Hello World", doesn't go passed the bounds of the rectangle when Spacer() is used. How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to accomplish can be achieved by just using a `ZStack` and specifying `.topTrailing` alignment:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height/3.25)
                    .shadow(radius: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)

                Text("Hello World")
                    .padding(.trailing, 40)
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Alternatively:

You can forego the `ZStack` and make the `Text` an `.overlay()` of the `Rectangle()`.  Here I kept your `VStack` and just made it an `overlay` which keeps it from going beyond the `Rectangle`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height/3.25)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Hello World")
                        }.padding(.trailing, 40)
                    
                        Spacer()
                    }
                )
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```